# Why do we use "a" in front of "unique" instead of "the"?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

When I read math books, I see sentences such as

> x=2 is a unique solution of the equation.

I interpret the word **unique** as **only one**. As far as I know, **a** is used for something arbitrary, while **the** is used for something unique. Then shouldn't we use **the** in front of **unique**? Or maybe I am misunderstanding the meaing of **unique**. Is the following sentence correct?

> The Moon is a unique satellite of the Earth.

Comment: "x=2 is a unique solution of the equation" sounds odd in itself.  "x=2 is the only solution to the equation" makes the same point unambiguously.  (Or, "x=2 is a unique solution to the equation because it is the only solution where x is an even number" for an example different unambiguous point)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence

> The Moon is a unique satellite of the Earth.

is grammatically correct, however, it is ambiguous and may not mean what you think it does.

If what you meant to say is that Earth only has a **singular** satellite then the way to say it is :

> The Moon is the **only** satellite of the Earth.

If what you meant was that of all ***of Earth's*** satellites, the Moon is the **only one** of its kind, then

> The Moon is a **unique** satellite of the Earth because we never see its far side.

**Unique** is a funny word and well, it's, **unique** (bad pun intended...)

One trick I use to figure out whether to use **a** or **the** is to look at the phrase in the absence of **unique**

> 1) The Moon is **a** satellite of the Earth.
>   2) The Moon is **the** satellite of the Earth.
>   3) The Moon is **a unique** satellite of the Earth.

#1 sounds good while #2 doesn't, therefore use **a** in #3

Comment: To elaborate on this answer: the English word _unique_ has evolved to mean "very special", whereas the original French word means "one and only".

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem understanding your sentence explaining *unique satellite*. What do you mean by *the Moon is the only one of its kind*? Does the sentence mean that there are many satellites of the Earth and the Moon is just one of them? Or does it mean that there is only one satellite in the universe? Both interpretations seem weird. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Hwang, I've edited my answer in response to your question. It means that there are several satellites around Earth, and the Moon is **different from the rest** *because*... It does not mean the Moon **is just one of them** since if it **was just one of them**, it would **not be unique**. **Unique** in this sense means **to be the only** ***thing*** **to have certain characteristics that make it standout**.  Hope that helps

Comment: If my comment helped you **right now**, then you would say: **I understand**. If you figured it out **before** I wrote my comment, the you would write **I understood**... Keep asking questions!

Comment: I think your explanation about the ambiguity is right but the trick explanation is misleading since it leads to "therefore use 'a unique'", instead it should lead to "therefore don't use the confusing word unique, instead modify 2) to be more explicit -> "the only satellite".  Unique is just not a good word to use here, making it "work" still leaves a very odd phrasing. - Also, 2) sounds good to me (given context: natural satellites.

Answer (score 1):

**A** is being used as the *Indefinite Article*. This implies that there are *numerous* solutions available, and of those available solutions **x=2** happens to be unique.

If it was the Definite Article **the** solution then the *unique solution* would also be the *only solution*.

The indefinite article in this sense illustrates an *example*.